# Correct spelling of porte-vues

Tags: orthographe, pluriel, mots-composés

Do we write un [*porte-vues*](http://www.amazon.fr/porte-vues-Fournitures-de-bureau/s?ie=UTF8&page=1&rh=n:192419031,k%3aporte%20vues), *porte-vue*, *porte vue* or *porte vues*? I cannot find the word on *Le Petit Robert*. I'm actually not even sure whether it's *un* or *une* (I would guess "un porte-vues").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ce mot est trop récent pour entrer dans le vocabulaire académique.

Intuitivement, comme *porte* employé ici comme verbe est aussi un nom féminin, il convient de mettre le *tiret* pour le relier à *vue*.

Je n'ai pas d'exemple en tête où un verbe dans cette situation serait mis au féminin, mais le *masculin* s'impose pour éviter toute confusion à l'oreille avec la *porte* que l'on ouvre ou ferme,

Selon votre lien il y a plusieurs vues rassemblées sous la même reliure, le *s* s'impose.

Je suis d'accord avec votre conclusion pour la graphie qui concerne *les porte-vues* (sans *s* à *porte* qui est un verbe).

Comment: The first time I heard it was around 20 years ago. It might have been used before that, but then I wasn't born :)